# Pointer of array output

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have the below program in C:

```
main() {
    int arr[5]={100,200,300};
    int *ptr1=arr;
    char *ptr2=(char *)arr;
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(int));
    printf("%d   %d",*(ptr1+2),*(ptr2+4));
    return 0; 
}
```

Its output is as follows:

```
4
300 -56
```

Please explain the last output. As per my understanding the last output should be 44 rather than -56.

Comment: Why do you think it should be `44`?

Comment: It depends on `endianness`

Comment: Ok I had run it in compiler where int is 2 bytes. In that case it gives output as 44. Well it depends also on how many bytes an integer takes.

Comment: Yea, with two byte ints, that code picks out the first octet of `300`, which is stored as `44, 1`.

Answer (score 4):

You are picking out the first octet of `arr[1]`. Your machine is little endian with 4 byte `int` and so the 4 octets that make up `arr[1]` are, written as decimal:

```
200, 0, 0, 0
```

So you are interpreting the octet 200 as a `char`. Your `char` is signed, and your machine uses [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).

The binary representation of 200 is

```
11001000
```

Since the most significant bit is set, this is a negative number when viewed as a signed value. So, to work out the magnitude of the negative value, we invert the bits, and add one.

```
00110111
```

is 55 in decimal. Hence the value output is -56.

Comment: One could also say that, since values wrap around, and char is obviously interpreted as being in the range -128 - 127 (by this particular compiler), 200 is interpreted as the negative value 200-256 = -56.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you expected 44 what it would be if you had `sizeof(int) = 2`, because then *(ptr2 +4) would point to 300= 256 + 44 with a hex representation of `1002E` and a last byte of `2E` or 44 in decimal.

To get it independently of the size on an int, you should write :

```
printf("%d   %d",*(ptr1+2),*(ptr2+(2 + sizeof(int)));
```

But it will still depend on endianness, and give 0 on a big endian computer ...